# Getting around the Wengen/Grindelwald/Jungfrau region

Tags: public-transport, switzerland, skiing, jungfrau-region, wengen

We are spending a couple of days in Wengen and trying to get a grip on the trains here. We bought single tickets from Zurich airport which may have been a mistake given the Swiss Rail Pass. But it doesn't seem to cover the Wengen-Grindelwald mountain train from what I can see. Single tickets on this network seem pretty steep.

What is the best option for two or three trips from Wengen to at least Grindelwald and Jungfraujoch?

Also - is the mountain train included when you a buy a ski pass?

(It seems that the best skiing can be found in Kleine Sheidegg up the mountain. Some slopes are open, some are not)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you noticed, the Jungfrau area and especially the Jungfraujoch are very expensive. It doesn't help that they reorganised their website in such a manner that there are no price lists I can find there. [Here is a pricelist](http://eigernordwand.ch/downloads/jungfrau-winter.pdf) from another website in German.

The map on the second page gives you an overview over which ticket you need if you go for a ski pass. For your case to see Grindelwald, you'd have to go for the 'Sportpass Grindelwald-Wengen' (CHF 63 for 1 day, CHF 170 for 3 days). As you can also see from that map, this only covers the train up to 'Eigergletscher' if you want to go all the way up to the Jungfraujoch, then you'd have to buy a connecting ticket. If you don't actually want to ski, you could also go for the hiking or sledging passes which are available from 2 days onwards (CHF 108)

To go up to the Jungfraujoch, if you take a skiing or hiking pass of 3 days or more, there's a [special offer for a cheaper connecting ticket](https://www.jungfrau.ch/shop/en/tickets/bergbahn/angebote/jungfraujoch-top-of-europe/top-ticket-spez) at CHF 49. If not the regular [connecting ticket](https://www.jungfrau.ch/shop/en/tickets/bergbahn/angebote/jungfraujoch-top-of-europe/jungfraujoch-top-ticket-anschlussticket-zum-sportpass) is CHF 61. If you just want to go up to the Jungfraujoch from Wengen, then the [price is CHF 176](https://www.jungfrau.ch/shop/de/tickets/bergbahn/angebote/jungfraujoch-top-of-europe/billete-jungfraujoch). It won't pass by Grindelwald though, so that be another ticket you have to buy. A return ticket to [Grindelwald](https://www.jungfrau.ch/shop/en/bergbahn/ticket?date=2016-12-31&from=Wengen&to=Grindelwald&trip_type=T&class=second) will cost you CHF 31 if going by Zweilütschinen or CHF 110 when going via Kleine Scheidegg (scenic route). The second option would be a bit stupid though, as this would also be included in the cheaper ski pass.

So if you want to go skiing as well, you are probably best off buying a 3-day pass with a connecting ticket which won't cost much more than a single ticket up to the Jungfraujoch.

As far as I know there's no real way to get around this, unless you have a Swiss half-fare card or something like that.

*Note: All prices are valid for the 2016/17 winter season. The special offer for the connecting ticket is only valid until January 2017.*

Answer (score 3):

The map on [this page](http://www.swissrailways.com/sites/default/files/upload/documents/uebersichtskarte_2017_en.pdf) will tell you whether the Swiss Rail Pass offers a discount on the privately-owned mountain railways you wish to take. That may change your calculations.

Depending on your tourism style, you may get value because the Rail Pass doubles as a Museum Pass on its days of validity.

Comment: Yeah, I always use that map as a reference as well. It is worth noting that the Jungfrau area is especially complicated as the discount is only 25% for the Swiss Rail Pass, but 50% with other passes.